# How to do website searching from Android App

Tags: android, google-search-api

How would I implement a web search in my app, that searches eBay for example, from a user input?

Comment: please try to be specific about what you want to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this:

1. Put an `editText` to capture user input
2. Figure out how the ebay URL works, (Eg. for Google, `https://www.google.com/search?q=[Your-keyword-here]` can get you to the search result of your keyword)
3. Load the URL in a `webView`

There you go!

---

Edit:

This might work for Ebay:

```
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=[Your-keyword-here]
```

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking too, seems like that's the easiest way. Would you know of any way of only showing afew select products from the list, instead of the entire webpage?

Comment: Maybe you can check out Ebay's developer API :D This might be what you are looking for: https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/rest-request-components.html